# When to use OAuth in Django? What is its exact role on Django login framework?

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, django-oauth

I am trying to be sure that I understand it correctly:

Is OAuth a bridge for only third party authenticator those so common like Facebook, Google? And using it improves user experience in secure way but not adding extra secure layer to Django login framework? Or only Authorization Code grant type is like that? Can I take it like this?

Comment: Is there any thoughts or solution?

Comment: Strange that this doesn't have an answer. Started a bounty. Let's see.

Comment: OAuth is more of a protocol, a set of rules that dictate how websites can share information about you, and what information about you they can share.
You may want to take a look at this: https://lifehacker.com/understanding-oauth-what-happens-when-you-log-into-a-s-5918086
Have you checked out the toolkit: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#django-oauth-toolkit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is OAuth?

According to [RFC 6749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749):

> The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party
> application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service, either on
> behalf of a resource owner by orchestrating an approval interaction
> between the resource owner and the HTTP service, or by allowing the
> third-party application to obtain access on its own behalf.

Essentially, it is an **authorization protocol** used to share permissions between multiple applications.

If you decide to implement OAuth, your application will be the one to allow other services to programmatically view your users' data and act on their behalf, if needed.

Whenever an application requires access to another service that you use, it probably uses OAuth to perform those actions. (e.g. When games used to ask us to allow posting on Facebook on our behalf.)

### What OAuth is not?

By looking at your question, I feel like there's a misunderstanding of OAuth.

OAuth **is not** a bridge for third-party authentication methods. If you are looking for this type of authentication mechanism, you should take a look into [Single Sign-On (SSO)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7642). For Django, you can use [django-simple-sso](https://github.com/divio/django-simple-sso).

### Does it enhance security?

**Depending on the use case, yes, it can enhance security.**
If your application needs to exchange information with other services, it is a good practice to limit what these third-party services are able to do in your app, feature and time-wise.

Let's say, for example, that your user needs to give permission to another application to gather information from yours:

- If you were to use the old-fashioned e-mail and password combination method, these **credentials would be exposed** in case of this third-party service had a data breach.
- Using OAuth on the other hand is much more secure, as the credentials stored in the server would not contain the user's password and have **very specific [roles](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.3)**, apart from being **[easily revoked](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.2.1)**.

Comment: One comment - OAuth is an authorization protocol, not an authentication protocol. OpenID Connect is an authentication protocol built on top of OAuth.

Comment: So if I want a "Sign in with Google" option in my app, for the user to repeatedly sign in without a password, is that SSO? or OAuth?

Comment: @JohnMc That would be accomplished by implementing SSO

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Django app I would say that you don't have to implement OAuth - you should be fine with any login functionality Django offers.

OAuth is commonly used when different services talk to each other. These don't have to be third-party services, they can belong to the same party. For example, when you have a Single Page Application or a Mobile App that want to call your backend API to get some data. Then it's better to use OAuth as it is a standard and it helps you to implement authorization in a secure way.

When you think about "login with Google/Facebook", what you actually want is an SSO solution (Single Sign-On). That solution is very often implemented with OpenID Connect (OIDC), which is a protocol built on top of OAuth. Still, you can use just OIDC to log a user in with Google, get an ID Token, and then be able to authenticate the user to your Django app based on the ID Token from Google. You don't need OAuth for that (in the sense, that you don't need to get access tokens from Google, you don't need your own Authorization Server, and you can rely on cookie-based sessions).